# How do you modify the 'post_parent' of a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, attachments

I want to be able to edit the post_parent of a custom post type.  Basically in my use case I want to mimic how WordPress uses attachments: have a custom post type that is sort of a subtype to post or any other post type.  WordPress uses the post_parent field on the wp_posts table to link attachments to their parent posts so I want to be able to do the same.  I've tried to use wp_update_posts but it seems to time out the connection when I try to call it during a post save.  Is there a way of editing the post_parent directly?

Comment: Show us the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi **@Manny Fleurmond**:

You can add the following HTML to a [**post metabox**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) you'll have an edit field that lets you edit the raw `post_parent` ID. Maybe with this knowledge you can build what you need?

```
<input type="text" id="parent_id" name="parent_id" 
       value="<?php echo $post->post_parent; ?>" />
```

Comment: Thank you.  That is pretty cool.  Didn't realize you could do this.

Comment: @Manny Fleurmond - Sure, glad I could help. It took me a while to figure it out, especially the use of `parent_id` instead of `post_parent`.

Comment: Nice solution, much less intrusive than the direct database intervention mentioned at http://wordpress.org/support/topic/changing-post_parent-by-costum-meta-box. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood the question you can set support for page-attributes when you register a CPT like this:

```
add_action( 'init', 'register_products_post_type' );
function register_products_post_type() {
    $labels = array(
        'name' => 'Products'
    );

    $args = array(
        'labels'        => $labels,
        'public'        => true,
        'rewrite'       => array(
            'with_front'    => false
        ),
        'has_archive'   => true,
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'menu_position' => 5,
        'supports'      => array( ..., 'page-attributes', ... )
    );

    register_post_type( 'products', $args );
}
```

A listbox will appear in the manage post page.